# Cannot install lektor in pyenv virtualenv: `clang' exists in these (other) Python versions

Tags: pip, clang, pyenv, python-watchdog

I'm trying to install `lektor` into a new virtualenv using `pyenv virtualenv`. I have no problem making a new virtualenv with Python 3.7.0, but when I try to `pip install lektor`, I get a build failure with `watchdog` and the following error message:

```
pyenv: clang: command not found

The `clang' command exists in these Python versions:
  anaconda3-5.0.0

error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 127
```

I understand that the anaconda3 version has `clang`, but I also have a version installed in `/usr/bin`. The output of `which -a clang` is:

```
$PYENV_ROOT/shims/clang
/usr/bin/clang
```

Can I manually set the shim to point to `usr/bin`? Or is there a different solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rotten solution, but it does work. By taking the shim for clang and temporarily moving it (e.g., `mv $PYENV_ROOT/shims/clang ~/Desktop`), `watchdog` can be installed, then the clang shim can be moved back to the original location. A better option would be for `pyenv` to default to the system versions of programs if a shim doesn't point anywhere in a given environment…

#### Alternative solution

The `pyenv` plugin [`pyenv-which-ext`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-which-ext) takes care of this class of issues by checking for the existence of utilities in the normal `$PATH` after seeing that they aren't present in the current environment. It's a quick install via `Homebrew`, took care of all my issues.